# How to use find_if in vector of vectors with different loops for rows and coloumns

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, vector, find

I want to use `std::find_if` with inequality in condition for `std::vector<std::vector<double> >`.

For example [image: pic] - here I have matrix M in Matlab (in C++ I created vector of vectors `M[i][j]` where `i` is column (vector) and `j` is row (vectors with elements).

Then I want to realize in C++ something what I have in Matlab:

```matlab
for j = 2:(sz - 1)  % (sz - 1) = M.size()
   k1 = j - find(M(j, 1:j - 1) > L, 1, 'last'); % j - last one index in red frame
   k2 = find(M(j, j + 1:end) > L, 1, 'first'); % first one index in blue frame
   ...
end
```

Here `(M(j, 1:j - 1)` are for red frames and `M(j, j + 1:end)` are for blue frames.

I search `k1` in red frames and `k2` in blue frames. I try to found `k1` (index of the last element above `0`) using `std::find_if`, but I can't understand why:

1. It works only when I write `x < L` instead of `x > L`
2. I get `0.2877` first, not `0.4055`.
3. Is it better to create two additional vectors for example `M1` and `M2` for
   `(M(j, 1:j - 1)` and `M(j, j + 1:end)`? Because there is no colon operator in C++. Or can I get what I want using `find_if`?

C++ code:

```
...
for (unsigned int j = 1; j < M.size(); j++) {
   auto it = std::find_if(M[j].rbegin(), M[j].rend(), [&](const double &x) -> bool {return x > L; }); // here without `j - ...` 
   auto f = *it2; // just for check what I get
}
...
```

Comment: You can use iterator arithmetics: Just pass `M[j].begin() + j` to `find_if` instead of `M[j].end()` to stop at index `j-1` (0-based) instead of at the end.

Comment: You will serve yourself well, and avoid needless headache, by correctly using 0-based array indexes when writing C++ code. Otherwise you'll be forever chasing elusive bugs. The first element in an array or a vector is `M[0]`, not `M[1]`. Here, for example, rbegin/rend will iterate over array element 0, and I'm pretty sure that you don't have it initialized.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If you are about `for (unsigned int j = 1; ...)`, - I need to skip all 1st row so I start my loop from 1 (1st row in C++ = 2nd row in Matlab)

Comment: @MaxLanghof  when I write: `auto it = std::find_if(M[j].begin(), M[j].begin() + j, condition);` - I see first elements from red frames, not the last. That's because I used not `rbegin()`, but when I use `rbegin()` - I get last elements in each row under zeros, but I need last elements only in rows which are above zeros

Comment: Well use `rbegin` etc. then. That too is a random access iterator.

Comment: I would suggest you use a proper matrix type. Look e.g. into the [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). Then you'll be able to create vector "views" of your columns or rows, and get their max element using a single function. There is no point in trying to re-invent the wheel!